# How can we stop increasing the size of parquet files when writting on disk ,by doing repartition

Tags: file, apache-spark, disk, controlling

I am trying to merge small files less than 512 mb in a hdfs directory. After merging the files size on disk is more than input size. Is there any way to control the size efficiently.

```
Df=spark.read.parquet("/./")
Magic_number=(total size of input file / 512)

Df.repartition(Magic_number).write.save("/./")
```

Repartition is causing lot of shuffling and input files are in parquet format.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator
val numBytes = SizeEstimator.estimate(df)

val desiredBytesPerFile = ???

df.coalesce(numBytes / desiredBytesPerFile).write.save("/./")
```

This will give you approximately the write number of bytes per file.

Comment: Kieran ,I am getting the number on which coalesce has to be performed thru other way .problem here is , input file size 681 MB with 1541 column ,after repartitioning(2) and writting  to disk, output file is size is 1.1GB ,so a total of approx 300+ MB difference . So this increased in size is giving hard time to me.

Comment: Without any transformations that is happening? And you're using the same compression scheme for both?

Comment: Yes it is happening without and transformation , files are not compressed in input ,but in output it compressed because of pyspark feature df.write.save ()